# so is it a postback or not

Tags: asp.net, postback

I'm causing a postback by clicking an asp:button.  I end up in a breakpoint on `Page_Load`, where `IsPostBack == true`.  Then, one breakpoint later, I end up in `Page_Load` where `IsPostBack == false`.

What the heck is going on?  I'm trying to understand someone else's code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first link click is a PostBack from the server and the correct behavior.  It sounds like the second PostBack is triggered because of a `Page.Redirect()` or a `Server.Transfer()` back to the same page.

This is a best guess until you provide additional details.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a blog post that may be helpful.

http://www.craigwardman.com/blog/2009/01/aspnet-multiple-page-load-problem.html

I was having the same issue because the src of one of my images was "" and that caused the page load to fire 2 times.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like 2 it could be 2 separate requests to the page - Check the IIS logs.

If not then its possibly a Server.Transfer(), or someone might be instantiating and calling the `Page_Load` method themselves for some reason (extremely unlikely, but easy to check by looking at the callstack)